# Python functions to convert Fortran math strings to C++

Tags: python, c++, syntax, fortran, format

I am reading in archived work from text files. The files include large sections of mathematical expressions that are written in FORTRAN (I am not sure if it is 77, 90 or something later, I don't know how much the math syntax changes between the versions if at all). I am using python for its ease of parsing and manipulating strings. I need to read in the mathematical expressions and output them in C++ syntax into a .cpp file template.

Are there any ways to convert the FORTRAN to C++ via python? There are hundreds of files so doing this manually is out of the question. I haven't found python packages that do so, not even FORTRAN to Python and then Python to C++.

I am aware of f2c but I am doing a lot of work with the files already in python and would like to keep all the manipulation in python if possible. Additionally, would f2c handle c++ syntax such as including "std::" in front of trig functions?

Comment: There are a few forks of the original `f2c` tool, but the official netlib one has supported C++ for a couple decades now, and the one that came with `gfortran` when it was a separate project from `gcc` did, so I'd assume whichever one you're using does as well. But to find out, `man f2c` and see. For example, [the netlib `f2c`](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/f2c.1) says "Convert Fortran 77 to C or C++", and has a `-C++` flag to "Output C++ code".

Comment: Meanwhile, the other alternative is to do the same thing `f70` does: parse the Fortran expressions to an AST, then translate to a C++ AST (which may be a trivial translation), then generate C++ source from that. If you don't want to write all the bits of that yourself (and you probably don't), there are probably plenty of parsers out there for Fortran—maybe even as an example project for PyParsing or the like—but Stack Overflow is not the right place to go for recommendations.

Comment: @abarnert.  gfortran never contained any part of f2c.

Comment: @Steve I guess I'm remembering wrong; `g77` says it uses a rewritten version of the runtime libraries from netlib `f2c`, so I assumed that's when the f2c on my old linux boxes also came from, but I easily could be wrong.

Comment: @abarnet, g77 is the Fortran compiler contained in GCC prior to 4.0.0.  After 4.0.0, gfortran is the GCC Fortan compiler.  AFAIK, gfortran never used any part of g77 or its runtime library.

Comment: With modern Fortran's `iso_c_binding` you might consider keeping the computational part in Fortran and call it from C++.